# PC won't start when 8-pin CPU power is connected, what can I do?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, troubleshooting

It does briefly start, but not even long enough to reach the BIOS.

- Motherboard: Z170A GAMING M7
- CPU: Intel i5 6600K
- RAM: Ripjaws V Black 3600MHz 2x8GB
- GPU: No GPU yet
- PSU: EVGA 600W (eu)

I've checked on the riser screws in case an extra was causing a short somehow. I've disconnected everything from the board except the 24-pin and the 8-pin and the fans, but have the same result.

I really need this to work, please help me out.